# Django: changing representation of a field in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a field what displays an average score and depends on another model's field. I use SerializerMethodField in order to get needed value. It looks like this:

```
class TitleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Titles

    def get_rating(self, obj):
        rating = obj.reviews.all().aggregate(Avg('score'))
        return rating
```

It works but doesn't return it in a way I need. Now I get data what looks like:

```
"rating" : {
    "score__avg" : some_value
}
```

How can I change it to:

```
"rating" : some_value
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give the aggregate expression a name, so with a *named* parameter:

```
def get_rating(self, obj):
    # returns {'rating': … }
    return obj.reviews.aggregate(rating=Avg('score'))
```

or you can unwrap it out of the dictionary:

```
def get_rating(self, obj):
    # returns … (value)
    return obj.reviews.aggregate(Avg('score'))['score__avg']
```

Comment: Thanks again, Willem :)